# MVC3: Guid data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have a project that gets data from the database. I made some modifications to the database fields in the model and now I am getting the error

```
The 'XXX' property on 'YYY' could not be set to a 'Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'.
```

XXX is the key of the class and is defined in the model as

> public string XXX {get; set;}

The data type of this field in my database is uniqueidentifier.

What is the "equivalence" of this data type in mvc3?

**EDIT**

I tried changing the datatype of XXX to

> public Guid XXX {get; set;}

but I got the error

> The 'UnallocatedId' property on 'YYY' could not be set to a 'Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'.

Comment: is your field in database not null ? or null ?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Please see edit. The field XXX is the primary key in the database.

Comment: `System.Guid` is the equivalent for `uniqueidentifier`. I think there is no casting needed. you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the error, you need to use the `Guid` type:

```
public Guid XXX { get; set; }
```